# TWRP: Failed to mount '/preload' (Invalid argument)

Tags: twrp, partitions, mount, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

With TWRP, on almost every operation I get

> Failed to mount '/preload' (Invalid argument)

My device currently can not boot, and this may have something to do with it, `/preload` is currently in `/etc/fstab`, I can see the entry here with

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p16 /preload ext4 rw 0 0
```

When I try to mount it, I get

```
mount preload/
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 on /preload failed: Invalid argument
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

From my `recovery.log`, I have

```
/preload | /dev/block/mmcblk0p16 | Size: 0MB Used: 0MB Free: 0MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
   Display_Name: preload
   Storage_Name: preload
   Backup_Path: /preload
   Backup_Name: preload
   Backup_Display_Name: preload
   Storage_Path: /preload
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files
```

I'm trying to flash LineageOS, but I'm really just curious about resolving this error message.

Comment: What about flashing full firmware with Odin ?

Comment: Then I would need a stock rom (I don't).. and I'm not sure how that ties into /preload being broken.

Comment: /preload stands for partition if I'm not wrong. You should fix it by flashing stock ROM with repartion option being ticked

Comment: Know where I can find stock rom?

Comment: almost anywhere on the Internet. Which model number is your device?

Comment: https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-note-101/SM-P600/

Comment: @Andy Yan, OP needs full firmware files which contain a script that wipes everything on the device.

Comment: @esQmo_ Then where do you find one of these? Even as a seasoned flashaholic I have no idea such a thing exists. // IIRC, all-in-one tar packages contain PIT files in them and would be suitable for repartitioning; standalone BL/AP/CP/CSC packages would just need a separate PIT file if he were to repartition.

Comment: @Andy Yan By full firmware files I mean 4 files firmware called "repair firmware" a few websites such as http://firmware.gem-flash.com,... Not all in one package contains a PIT file and you don't really need a PIT file if there is no reason to partitioning. https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=8970

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218564/install-pit-file-on-samsung-s8-sm-g950f maybe you can help?

Comment: try the same for /preload
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-data-t3830897 it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, but I can install treble roms, I installed Lineage 17.1 without problems but sometimes I see the message / preload invalid argument, size of partition 0, I am looking for a solution but this error does not disturb my device at all

in xda i encontered this => 
All you need to do is go to official download page, download your official latest rom and flash
Download the most recent firmware and flash in Odin. (There is instructions on how to download the correct firmware in the post)