# Install PIT File on Samsung S8 SM-G950F

Tags: root-access

I try to root my phone but now I get the error `Failed to mount '/preload' (Invalid argument)` on practially every operation in TWRP, so I read that I should replace the PIT-file with ODIN.

Is this source trustworthy:
https://zfirmware.com/download-samsung-galaxy-s8-g950f-pit-file/

Comment: if your device is functional in system mode, i recommend to just ignore this error in recovery mode. preload is not important partition, maybe your device don't have it